# Compilation issue

Tags: iphone

I am facing some compilation issues. In my iPhone app I am using some external library which I have placed in my Frameworks folder. But both these ".a" files and ".h" file comes in red color and they are not getting compiled. Any clue what I am doing wrong here.

It gives errors like not able to find classes of these external lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are red. Then those files are actually missing from your iPhone project. In order to fix this. Re-download the library (.a and .h) files, then add them into your project again.

I would recommend deleting the "RED" files first, and then re-add the files again.

If you're still having problems after following this. Drop a note.

Hope this helps...

Comment: It worked!!!    But now I am getting this error "Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1"

Comment: @abhinav, that is usually because it can't link a library.  Make sure your libraries and frameworks can be found under the Target's Build Settings for `Library Search Path`

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. But here, even if i give absolute path to my framework folder which contains these external jars...it is still giving the same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you're building against the Simulator. Depending on the external library, it might not have the dependencies for the Simulator. Try building to an actual device and see if that works.

Comment: Here the issue was, I was trying to build the app on IOS 4.0 which was missing in my XCODE.